# DevTools shows CSS rules being ignored: some help debugging?

Tags: css

Please could someone help me understand why the `div.fl` element shown in Developer Tools below has `display: block` in the Computed Style section?

It is being displayed as a block-level element.

But the list of CSS rules below shows that `display: inline ! important` is the rule with the highest priority - the `div: block` directive has a strikethrough.

[image]

I would like it to display inline, but I'm not sure what else I can do besides use `div.fl { display: inline ! important; }` in my code.

I'm afraid I can't link to the code, but could anyone even suggest where to start looking? I don't understand where the `block` directive could be coming from.

Debugging CSS = my least favourite part of coding.

Comment: I can't tell from your image what's going on. Please post some code or better yet, a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Showing us the computed style doesnt help much, can you show us the stuff from the "style" pane? It should tell you the matched selectors as well. Also if you are having the same issue in firefox, i would check it out with firebug, its a lot easier to tell what is overriding what and from what css in what file than with Chrome/Safari/Webkit built in dev tools. However even then its going to be hard for us to tell you without actually seeing the full css and markup.

Comment: By the way, it's `!important` without a space in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a `float: right` declaration in your screenshot. Floated elements are always rendered as blocks; you can't make your element `display: inline` if it's floated. See the spec for the [`float` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks! CSS will be the death of me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it floating or doing something that causes it to inherit display:block;? There are a number of CSS attributes that can change display types.